# Filtering Pandas Dataframe using OR statement

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to filter the whole df based on the value of two columns in the data frame.  I want to get back all rows and columns where IBRD or IMF != 0.

```
alldata_balance = alldata[(alldata[IBRD] !=0) or (alldata[IMF] !=0)]
```

but this gives me a ValueError

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(),       a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

So I know I am not using the or statement correctly, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

From the docs:

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
> data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These
> must be grouped by using parentheses.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Try:

```
alldata_balance = alldata[(alldata[IBRD] !=0) | (alldata[IMF] !=0)]
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. I should have read that part of the docs.

Comment: 6 years later I find myself here often... I'm a bit sad that the "natural python syntax" doeesnt work in this scenario, since I bet this trips people up all_the_time.

Answer (score 6):

You can do like below to achieve your result:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
....
....
#use filter with plot
#or
fg=sns.factorplot('Retailer country', data=df1[(df1['Retailer country']=='United States') | (df1['Retailer country']=='France')], kind='count')

fg.set_xlabels('Retailer country')
plt.show()


#also
#and
fg=sns.factorplot('Retailer country', data=df1[(df1['Retailer country']=='United States') & (df1['Year']=='2013')], kind='count')

fg.set_xlabels('Retailer country')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question it is posted under? If so, why are you going explaining `seaborn` along with it? Also, please take a look at how to [format your answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to note that you can use both of `or` and `|` inside the [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method:

```
alldata.query('IBRD!=0 or IMF!=0')
```

and

```
alldata.query('IBRD!=0 | IMF!=0')
```

both produce the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

## you can separate conditions with |

#like this

df1 = df[(df['age'] > 25) | (df['gender'] == "Male")]

Comment: Using `|` was already given in the other answers.