# Dataframe True False Value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this currently that works

```
df['AStrategy'] = df['Areturn'][df['BUY'] == True]
df['BStrategy'] = df['Breturn'][df['SELL'] == True]
```

I wanted to add a condition where I will only Sell when Buy is false as per below, but it did not work

```
df['AStrategy'] = df['Areturn'][df['BUY'] == True]
df['BStrategy'] = df['Breturn'][df['SELL'] == True & df['BUY'] == False]

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Why does it not work?

Any kind advise please? Thank you

Comment: You need to add parentheses for individual conditions I think.

Comment: Yes, like `df['BStrategy'] = df['Breturn'][(df['SELL'] == True) & (df['BUY'] == False)]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering Pandas Dataframe using OR statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461185/filtering-pandas-dataframe-using-or-statement)

Comment: Thank you guys, adding the parentheses works.. I didnt know that and spend quite some time thinking why it didnt... thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

```
df['BStrategy'] = df['Breturn'][(df['SELL'] == True) & (df['BUY'] == False)]
```

It should work, to apply more than one filter you need brackets

Answer (score 0):

If you are only checking True/False you can simply do this:

```
df['BStrategy'] = df['Breturn'][df['SELL'] & ~df['BUY']]
```

---

### Your problem

Is explained by [Python's Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Yours doesn't work because of: `==` has less proprity than `&`. However `()` has highest priority and thus enclosing your statement works.

The solution I gave you works because of: ~x having higher priority than `&`.

---

### Example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'SELL':np.random.choice([True,False],6),
    'BUY':np.random.choice([True,False],6),
    'Breturn':np.random.randint(10,size=6),
})

df['BStrategy'] = df['Breturn'][df['SELL'] & ~df['BUY']]

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
     BUY  Breturn   SELL  BStrategy
0   True        6  False        NaN
1  False        8  False        NaN
2  False        0   True        0.0
3  False        5  False        NaN
4  False        0   True        0.0
5  False        9   True        9.0
```